# How can I download or install all of the dictionaries?

Tags: internationalization

I find the dictionaries in `/usr/share/dict/` quite useful. How do I download (or install) all of them, for every language, without having to install every language pack?

Also, if the answer involves package management, how do I properly remove them again?

Comment: Be aware that there are languages using myspell and/or hunspell. So there is `usr/share/myspell/dicts/` and `/usr/share/hunspell`, where you find other dictionaries.

Comment: @Pit saved my life. I couldn't understand why I've installed `myspell-bt-br` but it wasn't shown at `/usr/share/myspell/dicts`. Turns out `pt_BR.dic` was at `/usr/share/hunspell`, even though there is no such package as `myspell-pt-br`. Go figure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the various packages (e.g. `wcatalan`, `wbritish-large` `wbritish-small`, …) don't follow a pattern so

```
 apt-get install words-\*
```

or similar will not work. Typing `/usr/share/dict` into the search box of Software Center appears to yield all the wordlists, but I don't know if that is exhaustive.

If you want spell checking without the wordlists,

```
 sudo apt-get install aspell-\*
```

will pull in the (larger set) of spell checkers which work on a larger set of languages but cannot yield the wordlist used to compile them.

Be forewarned, given the way the wordlists were generated (*cf.* [Steve Johnson CACM v28 1985](http://books.google.com/books?id=w7cfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22steve+johnson%22+unix++spell&dq=%22steve+johnson%22+unix++spell&hl=en&ei=d9pLTcSMN8zpgAfYoZHbDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBg)) from words and proper nouns actually encountered in documents, the extra words might not be obviously jargon or proper to a non-native speaker)